# Nokia 8 connected to USB, nor recognized

Tags: usb

Hello Ubuntu community,

I am quite new to Linux, so pardon me if this is a stupid question.
I am using Ubuntu 20.04, and I have connected my Nokia 8 phone to an USB port to upload pictures. However: there comes no qustion on the phone if it is ok to exchange data, it looks like the computer does not see that the Nokia is connected.

What do I have to do ?

Best regards,

Dirk

Comment: Does it work with other computers?

Comment: you can try and use `adb` tools as a solution check out this link https://www.xda-developers.com/install-adb-windows-macos-linux/

Comment: @ChanganAuto: yes, the Nokia 8 connected to USB works with a computer on OS Windows 7 and 10.

Comment: Problem solved: android-file-transfer-linux installed and this works !